# Delete from access database based on selected item in databound combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, ms-access, combobox

i have a databound combobox using VB2010 and MS access as the DB.. When i click on a button, the selected item in the combobox will be deleted from the database and no longer display in the combobox...

Comment: If you mean vb.net, best say so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

Create a form called ComboDeleteExample with a combobox and a button.  To create the database, I just dumped the SQL Server AdventureWorks database Products table into Microsoft Access.  If you don't have SQL Server or Adventure works, just create a Product table with two columns; ProductID (int) and Name varchar(25).

Copy this code into the form:

```
Public Class ComboDeleteExample

    Const _ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\Database1.accdb;"
    Private dtProducts As New System.Data.DataTable("Products")

    Private Sub PopulateCombo()
        Using conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(_ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim sqlCmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from product", conn)
            Dim dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            dtProducts.Load(dr)
        End Using

        ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", dtProducts, "ProductId", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dtProducts
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboDeleteExample_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PopulateCombo()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf (ComboBox1.SelectedItem) Is System.Data.DataRowView Then
            Using conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(_ConnectionString)
                conn.Open()
                Dim row As System.Data.DataRowView = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, System.Data.DataRowView)
                Dim sqlcmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(String.Format("delete * from product where productid={0}", row.Item("ProductID")), conn)
                If sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                    row.Delete()
                    dtProducts.AcceptChanges()
                End If
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: when i click the button, an error appeared said that syntax error in query expression at line If sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
what can cause this...

Comment: Validate that the SQL statment above it is correct.  If you are not binding the combobox properly, then there will not be a set value for ProductId on the row.  You can take String.Format("delete * from product where productid={0}", row.Item("ProductID")) and evaluate it in the immediate window;  it should produce a valid SQL which you can execute in Microsoft Access.  Likewise, you can interogate the value of row.Item("ProductID"))